# my array of object is stored twice in local storage

Tags: angular

```
  select(product){

     let products =[]
      products.push(product)
       products.forEach((key) => {
        key["quantity"] = 1;
      })


  localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(products))
}
```

this is my component.ts file, i have been storing my product array = [{id: 48, title: "Drink", price: 30, category: "Drink"}].
it is storing in local storage but twice like this...

[{id: 48, title: "Drink", price: 30, category: "Drink",…}]

:
{id: 48, title: "Drink", price: 30, category: "Drink",…}

Comment: Twice?? there will be only one key `cart` in your localStorage. Probably your products is populated incorectly,

Comment: yes twice.. instead of storing single array it gets store twice

Comment: When you do `localStorage` in the console of your developer tools, you see two keys with name: `cart`? can you post that part of the console? Even a screenshot will do

Comment: [{id: 48, title: "Drink", price: 30, category: "Drink",…}]

: {id: 48, title: "Drink", price: 30, category: "Drink",…}, iam getting this in key section

Comment: Then not here but somewhere else in your code, you are setting the `localStortage`, you should find that code.. This is not your whole code right? you are setting `localStorage` somewhere else too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get confuse brother it is saving only once in an array.

It is just displaying the 0th index value to you in local storage.

Your array length saved in local storage is one you can check.

[image]